# What are the default settings for '/etc/hosts' and '/etc/hostname'?

Tags: 16.04, hostname, hosts, etc

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I recently started learning DevOps and got a bit crazy with my `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` files. In my frantic attempt to spin up a couple of servers from my local machine I lost track of the default settings, and was just curious to know what they are/were.

As I recall `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` had only one entry, which was the username of my local machine. However I'm not entirely sure.

By any chance does anyone know what the default settings are with a fresh install?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They are based on what you specified as the hostname when you installed: in my below examples "myhostname" is the name you chose.  The defaults look a bit like this:

/etc/hostname

```
myhostname
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 myhostname

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Note I don't put the domain part into /etc/hostname - opinion is divided on whether to do this but I've experienced server software that breaks if a FQDN is in /etc/hostname whereas I've so far had no issues caused by only the hostname there.

Comment: and myhostname is in /etc/hostname.

Comment: That's what's there is it not?

Comment: in 20.04 the `127.0.0.1 localhost` is on first line instead `127.0.1.1 myhostname`

Comment: In recent versions the default contents of /etc/hosts have changed, so I've updated the answer, but it hasn't changed in a way that would have any noticeable effect so the older contents would have been fine.

The order of items in this doesn't matter either.